# asp.net/ C# screen scaping done easily?

Tags: .net-4.0, screen-scraping

whats the simplest way to do screen scraping using c# and .net 4.0?

are their libraries i can reuse? i think i heard of an html tool pack for this but can not find it now...

Comment: Do you mean HTML Agility Pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing *should* be done with the HTML Agility Pack.  I've never used it so I don't know if it will connect to the web pages for you or not.  If not, you should be able to use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).